# What do I return and how from a SOAP service?

Tags: java, rest, soap, exception

I am refactoring some SOAP and REST services.  The SOAP services respond with the requested entity and nothing else.  For example, a GET returns the XML representation of the entity that was requested.  For errors, they throw standard exceptions.  The REST services have identical behaviour.

I am modifying the REST services to throw WebApplicationExceptions and return proper http codes (e.g. http 201 for a successful post instead of always returning http 200).  I am unfamiliar with SOAP, so I question what, if anything, needs to be changed.

What are the best practices for SOAP around:

1) Returning http codes (e.g. return a http 201 for POST/creation requests) for success and error cases?  If so, how?

2) Throwing exceptions?  Do you throw for all errors, including invalid data sent by the caller of the service?  Should it be a SOAP exception or a WebApplicationException?

I am looking forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP is made to be functional independent of the transport layer.  Though you aren't using it, SOAP is capable of being sent through different protocols such as SMTP.  Therefore, best practices would dictate that

1) You shouldn't be returning HTTP codes at all in your return message.  In fact, you probably aren't able to.  Success/error messages are generally going to be defined in either a custom SOAP header or the response body (response body method is simpler).

2) Every exception thrown by the web service should be a SOAP exception.  This way, the client, whatever it may be, can interpret the SOAP exception and act appropriately.

Comment: Thank-you for the feedback.  There are a couple questions which I could not answer from your reply.  Do you throw exceptions for all errors (e.g. a failed guard clause on passed in data)?  And, do you throw SOAP exceptions or WebApplicationExceptions?

Comment: All exceptions that you return to the client should be of type SoapException.  What constitutes an exception and what doesn't is a design decision.  For example, if the SOAP request includes a primary key and you can't find that key in your database, that might be more appropriate as an error marked in the SOAP response.  On the other hand, if the database connection is down, that might be worthy of a SOAP exception.  It's similar to a method: to indicate an error, you can either throw an exception or return a response value indicating an error, and leave it up to the client to interpret.

Comment: +1 For #2 especially. Microsoft SharePoint will "differ" between returning a SOAP-less 500 (if input XML is malformed, but only sometimes) and returning a SOAP exception. Most terribly annoying.